# Average two identically formatted Data Frames in Panda's

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes that are loaded from CSV files.  Each has two columns, column A is an id and is the same value and order in both CSVs.  Column B is a numerical value.

I need to create a new CSV with column A identical to the first two and with column B, the average of the two initial CSVs.

I am creating two dataframes like

```
df1=pd.read_csv(path).set_index('A')
df2=pd.read_csv(otherPath).set_index('A')
```

If I do

```
newDf = (df1['B'] + df2['B'])/2
newDf.to_csv(...)
```

then the newDF has the ids in the wrong order in column A

If i do

```
df1['B'] = (df1['B'] + df2['B'])/2
df1.to_csv(...)
```

I get an error on the first line saying "Value Error: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

It seems like this should be trivial, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `df1[B]` correct, or you meant `df1['B']` ?

Comment: meant df1['B'], edited, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `merge` instead of setting an index.

I.e. We have these dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "B": [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "B": [7, 4, 3, 10, 23]})
```

Then we merge them and create a new column with the mean of both B columns.

```
together = df1.merge(df2, on='A')
together.loc[:, "mean"] = (together['B_x']+ together['B_y']) / 2
together = together[['A', 'mean']]
```

And the together is:

```
    A   mean
0   1   5.0
1   2   4.0
2   3   4.0
3   4   8.0
4   5   15.0
```